# no matching function call with two types of strings

Tags: c++, function, templates

my driver is calling a find function with a remove function like this:

```
remove(find(p, string("Hog")));
```

my find function is :

```
Node <T> * find(Node <T> * & pHead, T & e)
```

and my remove function is:

```
Node <T> * remove(const Node <T> * pRemove)
```

the error is saying that there is no matching function call between:

> find(Node >*&, std::__cxx11::string) (what the driver is calling)

and

> find(Node*&, T&) [with T = std::__cxx11::basic_string] (what my find function is using)

the only difference I can see is for the string data the driver is using: `std::__cxx11::string`
and mine just has `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>`.

I don't know what the difference between these two is. any thoughts on how to get this function call matching?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot bind a temporary to a reference because typically the temporary dies immediately and a reference to it dangles. In the call it survives untill return though. You can solve the problem by changing the function to:

```
Node <T> * find(Node <T> * & pHead, const T & e)
                                    ^^^^^
```

`const &` prolongs the lifetime of the temporary until the return of function.

The alternative solution would be to not to use a temporary:

```
string s("Hog")
remove(find(p, s));
```